# User's Personal CSS Stylesheet in Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, styles

I have looked around but I can't find a lead on what I need to do to make the following possible:

This question assumes I have all model controllers working properly and the named CSS attributes are defined in the default stylesheet.

I am wanting users to be able to  select a few CSS attributes to personalize their own theme when they login.  The basics attributes would be the "body" and "page-wrapper" colour. (foreground)

I am wanting them to be able to select these attributes (from a form?) in the user's edit page.  (which is already created)

Any ideas as to how I could make this work or a good lead in the right direction?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach is via javascript, generating an style tag on the head with the desired styles. Jquery gives a simple way to do that, and you can store the styles on a column in your model.

Something like this:

```
class User
  attr_accesible :styles
```

view.erb

```
<script>
  // Assume the @styles attr has something like "body { background-color: #567;}"
  $('head').append($('<style>').html('<%= @user.styles %>'))
</script>
```

@styles will be another column in your model, so you should add it with a migration

```
rails g migration addstylestousers styles:string
```

in your form.erb

```
<%= f.label :styles %>
<%= f.text_field :styles %>
```

I think it's simple enough for the user to put the css style here as long as you give him enough tips like "add `body { background-color: red }` in this field to make you background red!".

About serialization, consider [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Saving+arrays%2C+hashes%2C+and+other+non-mappable+objects+in+text+columns).

If you want to nest the styles, then the script will be

```
//Lets say that the user stored on @bgcolor and @fgcolor only css color codes, like '#222' or 'blue'
var bgc = '<%= @user.style.bgcolor %>'
var fgc = '<%= @user.style.fgcolor %>'
var style = 'body { background-color: ' + bgc + '; foreground-color: ' + fgc + ' }'
$('head').append($('<style>').html(style))
```

Remember that relationship should be `User has_one :style` on this case. However, nesting it's getting yourself into more problem, I don't think it's worth it at all.

Comment: Ok great thanks.. but I am confused when you say store the styles in the user model.  Also, I am assuming users would select the styles from a form?  If so, how would the "styles" attribute be implemented into that.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's many ways you could do that. If @styles were simply a string, you could add an input to let the user edit it, assuming that he/she will be able to do that if you give them some tips.

Comment: Or, you can make @styles a serialized hash and manage it with a more complex form.

Comment: I kinda get what you are saying, but I guess I don't understand some of your terminology as "serialized hash".  I do understand string but "let the user end it" I do not.  Is it possible to show a simple form example or how/where I would define" @styles?  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks so much! But one more thing to bother you with.  Let's say I made a joint relationship where the models would look like this: User has_many :styles | Style belongs_to :user , attr_accessible :bgcolor, :fgcolor | So let's say the form for bg color allowed hexidecimal characters and a user entered in #999999 as in the :bgcolor field.  How might the javascript look in this scenario.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: Thanks!  I am trying it now!  I am not sure how it could get me intro a problem... is it because I would be have to properly define the current user?  I have done that... but I guess I will shortly figure out if I will have problems haha.  Thanks for you help :)